# Getting a JSON array of user's properties in same activity after login in

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have a login page in my android app and I can successfully login. But I want to have all the user's properties in my activity but I don't know how to get the data back and tried several ways. Here is my PHP script for login :

```
<?php
login();
function connectToDatabase(){
$connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
mysqli_set_charset($connection,"utf8");
return $connection;
}

function login(){

$connection = connectToDatabase();
$Username = $_REQUEST['Username'];
$Pass = $_REQUEST['Pass'];

if($Username!="" && $Pass!=""){

    $result = mysqli_query($connection,"select count(*) from user where usr_name='$Username' and usr_password='$Pass'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if($row[0]>=1){
        print "yes_user";
    }else if($row[0]<=0){
        print "no_user";
    }
    mysqli_close($connection);

}else {

    print "null";
}

}

?>
```

And here is my android side code that is working perfect for login but don't know where to get the JSON data and how :

```
private void login(final String username , final String password){

    AsyncHttpPost post = new AsyncHttpPost(
            "http://shayea.tk/sof/login.php"
    );

    post.setTimeout(5000);

    MultipartFormDataBody body = new MultipartFormDataBody();

    body.addStringPart("Username",username);
    body.addStringPart("Pass",password);

    post.setBody(body);

    AsyncHttpClient.getDefaultInstance().executeString(post, new AsyncHttpClient.StringCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(final Exception e, AsyncHttpResponse source, String result) {

            if(e != null){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainLoginActivity.this,"خطا در برقراری اتصال با سرور !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });

            }
            if(result.equals("yes_user")){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainLoginActivity.this,"شما با موفقیت وارد حساب کاربری خود شدید",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("userP", 0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sp.edit();
                        edit.putString("Username", username);
                        edit.commit();
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainLoginActivity.this , SuperAdminActivity.class));
                    }
                });

            }else if(result.equals("no_user")){

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainLoginActivity.this,"نام کاربری یا پسورد وارد شده اشتباه است",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            }else if(result.equals("null")){

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainLoginActivity.this,"موارد ورودی شما خالی میباشد !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            }

        }
    });
}
```

And here is my table structure which I want to get it's **usr_type** column and that is the only thing I need from the **user** table after user logs in :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
`org_pid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`usr_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`usr_name` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
`usr_profile_name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`usr_email` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
`usr_password` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
`usr_phone` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`usr_status` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`usr_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`usr_id`),
KEY `org_pid` (`org_pid`),
KEY `usr_type` (`usr_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=32 ;
```

Comment: Does your backend return you the JSON?

Comment: @Egor Actually the problem is that I don't know how to send and receive the data at the same time in an activity.
If you check my code you will see I just print `print "yes_user";` if the user exist and it isn't JSON type

Comment: I guess the first problem for you to solve is to make your server return data in JSON format, only then you can parse it in the app and store in a local DB.

Comment: @Egor Is this possible to send and Get the JSON data with same class?

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several security things that should have attention, but your solutions is simple.

```
<?php
login();
function connectToDatabase() {
$connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
mysqli_set_charset($connection,"utf8");
return $connection;
}

function login(){

$connection = connectToDatabase();
$Username = $_REQUEST['Username'];
$Pass = $_REQUEST['Pass'];

if($Username!="" && $Pass!=""){

    $result = mysqli_query($connection,"select org_pid, usr_id, usr_profile_name, usr_email, usr_phone from user where usr_name='$Username' and usr_password='$Pass'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if($row !== null){
        print json_encode($row);
    } else {
        print "no_user";
    }
    mysqli_close($connection);

} else {

    print "null";
}

}

?>
```

See that I changed the mysqli_query SQL statement, mysqli_fetch_array and print json_encode if has a result.

Take a moment to read the documentation of [PHP MySQLi](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [json_encode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Regards,

Comment: Now Can I get my data with android code I have written ?

Comment: I can't help you with java, I only have knowledge with PHP in this case. Make some tests with the PHP code... make requests passing **valid** params and **invalid** params and check how it will send back to you. IMHO, you should try some PHP microframeworks. Will make your life much more easy. [Lumem](https://lumen.laravel.com/) should be a great choice for you.